# Tiny MCE Line Break

Tags: tinymce

I am using tiny mce (3.4.7) with the following setting

```
forced_root_block: 'p',
force_br_newlines: true,
force_p_newlines: false,
convert_newlines_to_brs: true
```

When I type something for example great then press enter work the out put produced in chrome is `<p>great<br>work</p>` where as the same setting not working on firefox the output in Firefox is `great<br>work` which is missing the root block.

What do I need to do get the Firefox rendering the root node?